# "ADD" to DataGridView from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I have a winForm that I drag an xml file over and it populates the datagridview with the contents of the file. This works fine, what I'm trying to accomplish now is; once the first file has been loaded into the view I would like to be able to drag another file and have it add to the end or beginning of the view. So, in a nutshell I would like to be able to drag multiple files and have them all shown in the view together. Is this possible?
Thanks

```
    var Persons = new List<Person>();
        var lst = new List<Person>();
        var xml = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        var NewPerson = from person in xml.Descendants("Person")
                           from jobs in person.Descendants("Jobs")
                           from job in jobs.Descendants("Job")
                           select new Person
                           {
                               FirstName = person.Element("FirstName").Value,
                               JobTitle = job.Element("JobTitle").Value,
                           };


            foreach (var data in NewPerson)
            {
                Persons.Add(data);                         
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = Persons;
```

Comment: It is possible, yes.  But, are the files in the same format?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: They are exactly the same. I looked around online and am not even sure where to start. Possibly an insert and use a counter?

Comment: Can u show some code? How XML is displayed/bound to datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load your XML files into ADO.NET DataTable you can load consecutive files into a temp DataTable and then use [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) method to combine multiple data.

*UPDATE*

Based on your code the approach is even easier. Just declare

```
var Persons = new List<Person>()
```

somewhere outside of scope of this code (e.g. make it a global Form variable). This way every time you call your

```
foreach (var data in NewPerson)
{
   Persons.Add(data);                         
}
```

it will add items to list already populated by previous loads.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me, but I'm having trouble implementing could you provide example code?

Comment: Keep your code almost exactly as it is, just move the line `var Persons = new List<Person>();` from where it is now to directly below `public class Form1` or whatever your form is called

Comment: That was what I tried "Type or Namespace var could not be found, missing directive or assembly."

Comment: sorry instead of `var Persons = new List<Person>();` try `List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();`

Comment: I knew that, must of been a bad day yesterday. Still doesn't work, but I think it's an issue with the drag and drop. I will figure it out, thanks for the help.